# InApp Purchase: Is Approval from Apple required for new products?

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have implemented inApp Purchase in my app and the app is live now. The product list is present in an xml file and every time when the user opens the app, this xml file is checked for any new product available. Whenever a new product is added in that xml, the user will get a popup saying that a new product is available and then he can download the product.

I just wanted to know if I need Apple approval every time I add a new product in my xml file for download ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2009/tn2259.html

Comment: Step 6 says you need to generate the product ID on an Apple form but it doesn't say whether or not Apple actually check / approve the products you're selling, which I think is what kool4u was asking.

Comment: @Rup,yeah you are right. They have not mentioned anything about this.

Comment: link is dead :(